# Yii2: validatePassword return false with password another table

Tags: php, yii2

I saved a password in a table other than the User table.

In actionCreate of AnotherTableController:

```
$model->new_password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->new_password );
$model->save();
```

What I want is that there are two passwords to confirm the login. If the password that is in the User table fails, then try the password that is in this other table.

I edit this function in common\models\User.php

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}
```

To:

```
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    $admin = AnotherTable::findOne(['role' => 'admin'])->new_password;

    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash) || Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $admin);
}
```

But this condition `Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $admin)` return false.

Comment: have you verified by using `var_dump()` with both of them separately

Comment: Yes, I did. I even made "var_dump" of the function "crypt" and for the password that is in the table "user" condiz. With that of the other table, it's different. But the strange thing is that of the hash characters the first 32 are the same!